# Uncaught TypeError with iText pdf2Data

Tags: itext, pdf2data

I've installed iText pdf2Data version 4.3.2 on a clean Ubuntu 22 VM using the provided helper scripts as instructed [here](https://pdf2data.apryse.com/documentation/docs/editor-guide/Getting%20started/Installation/Deploy).

The installation works an I can login and start the creation of a new template. But when I get to the point to define data fields, an empty page is shown and and error is thrown in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: crypto.randomUUID is not a function
    uz http://192.168.30.120/editor/static/js/main.736088aa.js:2
    <anonymous> http://192.168.30.120/editor/static/js/main.736088aa.js:2
    <anonymous> http://192.168.30.120/editor/static/js/main.736088aa.js:2
    <anonymous> http://192.168.30.120/editor/static/js/main.736088aa.js:2
```

Tried with installing full application and editor standalone. Both give the same error.
Tried older versions 4.3.1 and 4.2.1 but both redirect to the login page after creating a new template.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Yuliya Ivaniukovich, added reverse proxy with https and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might be using a browser that doesn't support mentioned function. See https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_crypto_randomuuid for the list of supported ones.

PS: it should probably worth publishing a page with minimal supported browser versions list in documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Checked the browser versions. Tested with Firefox 120.0 and Chrome 119. Both versions are supported, so this isn't causing the issue.

Comment: According to https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/8820#issuecomment-1422703114 it looks like this is only available if your serve the app under https if you want to access it not from localhost. It can be setup using free let's encrypt certificates, see e.g.: https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/

Comment: BTW, mentioned issue is going to be fixed in 4.4.0 which is coming on Dec 6, so if setting up HTTPS is not an option you can wait for the fix a bit. As for redirect to login issue, you'll need to turn off secure cookies, see https://pdf2data.apryse.com/documentation/docs/editor-guide/Getting%20started/Installation/Customization#pdf2data_manager_refresh_token_cookie_secure